# Login with Facebook via Rails

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-1.8

As a relative newbie to Rails, I'm not sure how to approach this. I am looking to add a basic "Login with Facebook" feature to a practice site I am developing. I am stuck on two fronts:

1. Most Rails plugins dealing with Facebook seem out of date or poorly documented. I've encountered Facebooker (seems to have died off from what I see) and Mini_FB (more recent, but very little documentation). I tried to install Mini_FB, but I am still very unfamiliar about working with Gems. I ran `gem install mini_fb`, then `bundle install`, and finally added `gem 'mini_fb'` to my Gemfile, but my server complains of a `no such file to load` error. **Are there any other steps necessary to allow your app to use a gem?**
2. I am confused by how the "Login with Facebook" feature works from an overall birds-eye view. I understand that my App ID is passed into the login feature, and I ultimately get an access token (after resubmitting with my App Secret Key and an authorization code). **But how does this integrate with some kind of user system on a Rails site?** Since this access code doesn't last forever, do I need to renew it periodically? Is that done by simply waiting to catch an access token error from a Graph request and redoing the entire authorization procedure?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth)?

It supports a whole host of external providers, including facebook.

There are also a number of [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=omniauth) on it's use.

Comment: OmniAuth seems to provide generic OAuth authentication - which may be exactly what I need - but I simply don't understand the flow of authenticating a user via their Facebook account. Sure, I could follow the step by step, but when dealing with an issue like user account security, I'd like to understand what I am doing. Likewise, the Railcasts seem to deal with using OAuth via devise, which I am not using. Is there anything on the login via Facebook feature? I couldn't find any

Answer (score 1):

The correct order of installing a gem on your application would be first adding it to your Gemfile.rb, then running `bundle install` on your console. That being said, OmniAuth is probably the best path for you